# Splitting column on multiple spaces

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-2016

I have a bunch of entries in a spreadsheet which I want to split into two different columns.

The data looks something like this:

```
102483             STEIN LOKK B4-702
102482             STEIN LOKK BF-701
102413             RINGFUGEKULL 352X353X214 POS 2 Å1
102412             RINGFUGEKULL 352X353X135 POS 1 ÅI
102388             STEIN ISOLER MOSCONI MSB-475 500x250x 76
102387             STEIN ISOLER MOSCONI MSB-475 500x250x152
102384             OVNSFUNDAMENT CRADLE
102383             STEIN PLATE HA-040 KVAL,HSU95
102382             STEIN PLATE HA-039 KVAL,HSU95
102376             OLJE SYNT. MITRA 220
102341             KULL BUNN ÅI/ÅIIC  D 3365 x 550 x 490
102291             OLJE 10W-40 HAVOLINE FORMULA 3 DIESEL
102241             FETT MINERALSK PATRON STARPLEX EP 2
102231             OLJE FYRINGSOLJE NR.1 (F)
102211             CALDE SRRIX 14
102141             STEIN ISOLER AAM HIPOR 230X114X 76
102103             STAMPEMASSE ILDFAST AL-85-F
102102             STEIN BORGESTAD INSULATING FIREBRICKS
102101             STAMPEMASSE TYPE T-JUSTERT ELKEM
101964             PAKNING LEX THERMOSEAL PGF-1 LEX Ø12mm
101939             BOKS KOMPENSASJON F/OVN 4 OG 4B 1170
```

The delimiter is the bunch of spaces between the product number and name.

Trying to use Excel's text to columns function, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify more than one character as a delimiter, and if I only use one space it creates issues with splitting up the product name as well.

I wrote a small macro to do it for me (see below), but I feel like I may be making things overly complicated. Is there some simpler way to do this? Are there any obvious ways my approach can fail? I am not overly familiar with regexes, so I'm not sure if the pattern I've chosen is the best...

```
Sub split_column()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim reMatches As Object
    Dim c As Range
    
    Call deaktiver
    
    Set regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set ws = År_2017
    
    With regexp
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "^(\d+)\s{2,}(.+)$"
    End With
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
        Set reMatches = regexp.Execute(c.Value2)
        If reMatches.Count > 0 Then
            c = Trim(reMatches(0).SubMatches(0))
            c.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(reMatches(0).SubMatches(1))
        End If
    Next c
    
    Call reaktiver
End Sub

Private Sub deaktiver()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Private Sub reaktiver()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? you can achieve this using formula?

Comment: Hmm, so you suggest splitting using a formula, and then pasting the values into the columns? It's a rather large amount of rows so I want to avoid recalculations. @SiddharthRout

Comment: see Gary's answer below

Comment: Alternatively, simply open up PowerQuery and split the column on the leftmost space character only. That's all.

Comment: Oh, that's an excellent idea - thanks, @JvdV

Comment: @eirikdaude, just know that with a few more clicks you can also trim the values to remove trailing/leading spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data has a nice fixed format.  Rather than TextToColumns or VBA, in cell **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,6)
```

and in **C1** use:

```
=MID(A1,20,99)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

For non-regular data, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
=MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1,99)
```

for **B1** and **C1** respectively.

**EDIT#2:**

*Siddharth* has a good point.  It is better to use:

```
=MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1,LEN(A1))
```

rather than:

```
=MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1,99)
```

Comment: ++ Lol you beat me to it :D

Comment: The product number isn't always 6 numbers, that's an artifact of choosing a screenshot from somewhere in the middle of the list. I think similarly for the number of spaces between them.

Comment: @eirikdaude: Try this for the number in that case `=LEFT(TRIM(A1),SEARCH(" ",TRIM(A1),1)-1)` Paste this formual in `B1` and then paste this `=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(TRIM(B1))-1)` in `C1`.

Comment: @eirikdaude  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Do not hard code 99. If the length is more than 99 then it will get trimmed...

Comment: Thanks - I already tried with @SiddharthRout 's formulas with some small modifications, and they worked, so I assume yours will as well :-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is much simpler... and faster.

```
Dim input_, output_, i&
input_ = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Value2
ReDim output_(LBound(input_) To UBound(input_), 1 To 2)
For i = LBound(input_) To UBound(input_)
    output_(i, 1) = Split(input_(i, 1), "        ")(0)
    output_(i, 2) = Split(input_(i, 1), "        ")(1)
Next
ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row) = output_
```